# spring injection java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jsf

when I have injected the been AdminService the java.lang.NullPointerException appeared , although I inject this bean with the same way in  another managed bean and everything works :

```
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class ScheduleController implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1489523494215832724L;

        private ScheduleModel eventModel;

        @ManagedProperty(value = "#{adminService}")
        AdminService adminService;

        private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

        public ScheduleController() {
            List<Service> = adminService.getAllService();

        }

    public AdminService getAdminService() {
        return adminService;
    }


    public void setAdminService(AdminService adminService) {
        this.adminService = adminService;
    }
```

AdminService implementation:

```
Service("adminService")
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService,Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    AdminDao adminDao ;
    // adminDao injected by spring 

    @Transactional
    public void add(Admin admin) {
        adminDao.save(admin);

    }

    @Transactional
    public void edit(Admin admin) {
        adminDao.update(admin);

    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Admin admin) {
        adminDao.delete(admin);

    }

    @Transactional
    public Admin getAdmin(Integer adminId) {
        return adminDao.findById(adminId);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Admin> getAllAdmin() {
        return adminDao.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * @return the adminDao
     */
    public AdminDao getAdminDao() {
        return adminDao;
    }

    /**
     * @param adminDao the adminDao to set
     */
    public void setAdminDao(AdminDao adminDao) {
        this.adminDao = adminDao;
    }

    @Override
    public Admin authenticate(String adminName, String adminPass) {

        return this.adminDao.authenticate(adminName, adminPass);
    }



}
```

Comment: can you post the bean configuration?

Comment: i posted the AdminService Implementation

Comment: I suggest you for the service to have an application bean which access it (you can load it directly by code in order of using annnotations) and inject that bean in every single bean of your view, to be able to access the service wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the injected dependency **during** construction of the bean. This is obviously not going to work. You're basically expecting that it all works like follows under the covers:

```
ScheduleController scheduleController; // Declare.
scheduleController.adminService = new AdminService(); // Inject.
scheduleController = new ScheduleController(); // Construct.
```

This makes no sense. It's not possible to set an instance variable before the instance is constructed. Instead, it works like follows:

```
ScheduleController scheduleController; // Declare.
scheduleController = new ScheduleController(); // Construct.
scheduleController.adminService = new AdminService(); // Inject.
```

If you'd like to perform an action directly *after* construction **and** injection, then you should be using a `@PostConstruct` annotated method.

So, replace

```
public ScheduleController() {
    List<Service> services = adminService.getAllService();

}
```

by

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() { // Note: method name is fully free to your choice.
    List<Service> services = adminService.getAllService();

}
```

No need for the `<f:event>` mess. It also doesn't necessarily need to go in `<f:metadata>` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution ,  the problem is not a problem of injection is  a problem of call, I worked with this ways, and it works :

in the managed bean i add a init method  :

```
public void init(){ 
 List<Service> = adminService.getAllService();
}
```

and in the page.xhtml :

```
<f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{scheduleController.init()}"/>
</f:metadata>
```